# delete from menu some checked element in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-menu

I want to make a simple listview which displays all my files with checkbox, so it works like this, I select some files (I mean I click on each checkbox) then I click on Menu and in my Menu I have delete I click on it it deletes all checked element( Files). for my list view I made an adapter:

```
public class listFiles extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private List<FileModelListView> data;
    private static LayoutInflater   inflater = null;
    public         ImageView        imageView; 
    public  int    totalChecked    = 0;
    public  String checkedElements = "";



    public MyFilesProfilAdapter(Activity a, List<FileModelListView> files) {
        activity    = a;
        data        = files;
        inflater    = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageView   = new ImageView(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }



    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            CheckBox allCheck              = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
            TextView file_title            = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);


            allCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    totalChecked    += 1;
                    // checkedElements += checkedElementValue;

                }
            });



        return convertView;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public int getTotalChecked() {
        return totalChecked;
    }

    public String getCheckedElements() {
        return checkedElements;
    }
}
```

Now After I save evry checked element in my checkedElements, I want to get them in my function :

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case R.id.delete:
             // getckeckedElements How?
          break;
       }
       return true;
    }
```

Comment: means you want to delete all checked item which you check???

Comment: you need to more R&D about listivew check this link http://fundoocode.net/android-listview-checkbox-example-onitemclicklistener-and-onclicklistener/

Comment: yes exactly I need to delete checked item

Comment: You need to keep track of checked and unchecked items in the list using a boolean array. Set the position of list item as true or false in the array using onCheckedChangeListener.

Comment: @QuokMoon Yes this Part I did it when I check the item evrything works but now how I delete them, bc I need to delete each checked Item from the database so I need to have this list when I click on delete from my menu

Comment: so are you getting check item ??

Comment: Yes When I check each item I save them in one string, and I save the total checked item in one variable (c my code), now my problem I want to have this variable in my menu when I click on delete (or if there is another way how to do it I will be thankful)